# How Can I Force Tasks to Start?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I have a program that scans a network, it does so by using a lot of tasks (and parallel foreaches) that wait for data to return from the network. The problem is that although I know that these tasks barely use any CPU processing, the CLR doesn't and it insists to start off very slowly (especially since this is running on a two core CPU).

How can I force the CLR to start more tasks at the same time? Currently the program is waiting a lot, how can I make it open more connections at the same time?

Comment: Not sure if tasks give you any benefit here; you are waiting on I/O

Comment: "Currently the program is waiting a lot"  Your source code is blocking or the TPL stops spinning up threads? What have you done to narrow the issue down to the CLR?  Do you have code that demonstrates the issue you can post?

Comment: The TPL doesn't spawn more threads, it's stuck on a low number and rises slowly.

@AndrewBarber, I thought that tasks were supposed to replace threads in all C# code, another level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use async IO which does not require the TPL to start new threads, or you can start threads manually, or you can use `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`. Don't use the last solution though because this is a process-wide setting. Don't pick a global solution for a local problem.

Comment: We have tried in the past using SetMinThreads, I didn't do it personally but the other people on the project said it caused just trouble.

The issue with async IO is that it doesn't block the current thread but at the end this isn't what I want, I want to perform separate async IO operations at the same time.

Comment: I understand. I recommend you just spawn threads yourself. You can set the stack size in the constructor to a low value so you can spawn 100s of threads without problems. If you want to go into the 1000s you probably should test that first (might actually work fine!).